# EF Core entity relationships - one entity with multiple parent types

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a solution that will require auditing for some (but not all) entities in C#, using EF Core on a SQL Server database.

In order to support the auditing, and to define which entities require auditing, I've created the below classes to store the auditing entries;

```
public class AuditEntry : IEntity
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string EntityType { get; set; } = "";

    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string EntityName { get; set; } = "";

    public Guid UserID { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
    public DateTime ChangeDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    public ChangeType ChangeType { get; set; } = ChangeType.None;

    public List<FieldChangeAudit> Changes { get; set; } = new List<FieldChangeAudit>();
}

public class FieldChangeAudit
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string FieldName { get; set; } = "";
    [MaxLength(2000)]
    public string? OldValue { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(2000)]
    public string? NewValue { get; set; }
}

public enum ChangeType
{
    None, Created, Updated, Deleted
}
```

Also the below interface which is applied to any entity that requires auditing;

```
public interface IAudited: IEntity
{
    public string EntityName { get; }
    public string EntityType { get; }

    public List<AuditEntry> AuditEntries { get; set; }
}
```

Then within the `DbContext`, I've overridden the `SaveChanges()` methods, to call the following method:

```
private void ApplyAuditTracking()
{
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        foreach (var item in this.ChangeTracker.Entries<IAudited>())
        {
            AuditEntry audit = new AuditEntry();

            if(item.State != EntityState.Detached)
            {
                List<FieldChangeAudit> fieldChanges = new List<FieldChangeAudit>();

                foreach (var fld in item.Properties)
                {
                    if(fld.OriginalValue != fld.CurrentValue || item.State == EntityState.Added)
                    {
                        fieldChanges.Add(new FieldChangeAudit() { 
                            FieldName = fld.Metadata.Name, 
                            OldValue = (item.State == EntityState.Added) ? null : fld.OriginalValue?.ToString() ?? "", 
                            NewValue = (item.State == EntityState.Deleted) ? null : fld.CurrentValue?.ToString() ?? "" 
                        });
                    }
                }

                if (fieldChanges.Count() > 0)
                {
                    audit.ChangeDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    audit.EntityType = item.Entity.EntityType;
                    audit.EntityName = item.Entity.EntityName;
                    audit.UserID = this._UserID;

                    switch (item.State)
                    {
                        case EntityState.Modified:
                            audit.ChangeType = ChangeType.Updated;
                            break;

                        case EntityState.Added:
                            audit.ChangeType = ChangeType.Created;
                            break;

                        case EntityState.Deleted:
                            audit.ChangeType = ChangeType.Deleted;
                            break;

                        default:
                            audit.ChangeType = ChangeType.None;
                            break;
                    }

                    audit.Changes = fieldChanges;

                    item.Entity.AuditEntries.Add(audit);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This is then implemented on each audited entity in the following example of `Workspace.cs`;

```
public class Workspace : ITemporalTracking, IAudited
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    ...

    // IAudited members
    [NotMapped]
    public string EntityName => Name; 

    [NotMapped]
    public string EntityType => "Workspace";

    public List<AuditEntry> AuditEntries { get; set; } = new List<AuditEntry>();
}
```

While this *works*, my concern is the `AuditEntry` entity then has a column for each entity that is tracked, for example `WorkspaceID` is added for the above implementation.

As there will potentially be many entities that will be tracked, is there a better way to do this? I had considered having a separate auditing model for each entity model, however this may complicate things in the UI side, as well as the `DbContext` side, so was keen to have a single auditing entity, as this could potentially be searchable as well (e.g. all changes performed by user X between A and B).

Answer (score 0):

You could create some kind of "IgnoreAudit" attribute that you could add to the properties in each entity class that you don't want to be audited. In `ApplyAuditTracking` you would just have to check for the presence of the attribute and skip auditing for the property if it has the attribute.

Comment: My concern isn't the properties, as if an entity is audited, then all properties of that class will be tracked, my concern is that if I'm tracking 50 entities, then the AuditEntries table will have 50 relational FK columns added

Comment: Why is that a concern, isn't that what you want? You're only option is to do what you're doing now or have Entity specific auditing.